# Magento 1.9 ufter update adminhtml cache grid bug

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, cache

After update magento **1.9.2.2** to **1.9.3.8** I have bug. There no cache_grid. And when I use F12 in Chrome I see empty div tags instead of cache_grid.
[image]
[image]

### UPDATE 1

Found module which broke cache_grid that was bl_customGrid module 0.8.9 version. Trying fix this module, if you have some idea, please let me know!

Comment: there could be extension which is not compatible with your latest version, do you have any extension installed or it is blank magento ?

Comment: @Naveed thanks for your comment, yes i have a lot. i just cant find right module, and have no idea how debug it

Comment: any related to product pricing, or indexing schedule etc ? other wise it will be hard for your to debug it  ( disable all extensions and enabled 1 by one ) and check where does it crash.

Comment: @Naveed yes, I think there is, I need to check the modules associated with this?

Comment: @Naveed Thats great idea! thank you, ill try it!

Comment: Delete duplicate local.xml file from path app/etc

Comment: @Sourav thank you for comment, but i have no duplicate

Comment: send me details so i look into

Comment: Reference link : https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/1079

Comment: Did you remove cache & cookies from browser

Comment: @Sourav yes i saw it. Thank you. But its did not help. I already found module which broke adminhtml, when i deal with that i will create answer for this issue.

Comment: Disable eag grid manager via settings for that specific route